# DialogFlow, how to have responses with UI in it?

Tags: user-interface, dialogflow-es

I want to DialogFlow responses to have UI. One usage would be let users leave a message. So, it should have input name field, input email field, input message field and a send button.

How it can be done? I read their documents, googled and did not find anything.

Could anyone explain how to do it?

Comment: The UI is fairly platform dependent. What bot/agent platform are you planning on building for?

Comment: @Prisoner I want to use the bot on slack and slaask.

Answer (score 1):

There are several types of rich messages available in Dialogflow, such as text, cards, and images that can be defined in the console. For more info on inputting rich messages: https://dialogflow.com/docs/rich-messages#image.

Based on user queries you can extract values from parameters and entities to inform your responses, for more information on this: https://dialogflow.com/docs/actions-and-parameters#extracting_values.

And if you haven't already checked out the documentation for Slack integration in Dialogflow, https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations/slack.